# How to import a local git repo in lerna?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, lerna

I am trying to use lerna for the first time. When I use:

```
lerna import /path/to/my/create_react_app
```

This is the response:

```
lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: git rev-parse HEAD
lerna ERR! fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
lerna ERR! Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
lerna ERR! 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR! HEAD
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR!     at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
lerna ERR!     at Function.module.exports.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/execa/index.js:338:15)
lerna ERR!     at Object.execSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/@lerna/child-process/index.js:22:16)
lerna ERR!     at ImportCommand.getCurrentSHA (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/@lerna/import/index.js:129:34)
lerna ERR!     at ImportCommand.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/@lerna/import/index.js:98:31)
lerna ERR!     at Promise.resolve.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/@lerna/command/index.js:271:24)
```

How can I import a local repo into the lerna packages folder? (git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113))

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution: commit the lerna repo and try again .

Comment: Yup, had the same issue and finally noticed it in their doc: `Note: If you're importing an external repository **on a new lerna repository**, then do remember to **have at least one commit.**[emphasis added]` https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/import#readme